# How to reopen sqlite connection in flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlite

I am following the official SQLite tutorial from the [flask homepage](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/)

This is the first snippet:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/database.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

But when I use this code and make a call that queries the database twice it fails on the second call with:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.

Which makes sense, because the db connection gets closed at the end of the first call and then not reopened on the second call because `db is None` is false.

How can I reopen the database?

Comment: what is your flask version ?

Comment: The version is 0.12.2

Comment: thanks, can you attach your routes ?

Comment: I don't think the routes are useful because I have my logic in a controller and the db access in another file, so I would have to post a lot. Anything specific you are trying to find?

Comment: I think you can remove your database when you close it from your context so it will be opened on your next request.

Comment: How do I do this. I tried `setattr(g, '_database', None) which did not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove your database from context when you close it, it will be reopened on next request.

```
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/database.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
        g.pop('_database')
```

Comment: This sounds like the right solution, I will try it in a bit and report back